# codeigniter ecommerce Recommended or people also bought

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce

I want to implement "Recommended or people also bought" feature in my ecommerce site .

I would like to know what is the logic behind that feature so that I can code for it .

Answer (score 1):

I've created something similar, a good-better - best module. I made a new table in the database with with 4 fields; modelnumber(unique/primary) good, better, and best. When the client adds a product they add the appropriate model numbers for the good, better, and best models. Then just get this new information from the database when displaying a product on the front end. I also thought about automating it, maybe choosing products of like type and relevance, then choosing good/better/best based on price. Really that's all preference. If you were looking for someone to write the code for you, you're not going to find that here, especially with such a vague question. But if the eCommerce site in question uses a well know and widely used cart on the back-end, there could all ready be a module you could just install and be off and running in 20 minutes with.